# jQuery(form).serialize() failing with "URIError: malformed URI sequence"

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, urlencode

I have a web application that lets users comment on each others' posts. We use `jQuery.ajax()` to send new the comments to the server, and it seems to work reliably in our testing.

```javascript
jQuery(".post form.add-comment").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/comment",
    data: jQuery(this).serialize()
  });
});
```

However, we automatically collect client-side JavaScript error logs from our users (using Sentry), and there are occasional errors that looks like this:

```
URIError: malformed URI sequence jquery.min.js:4:25041
```

This error seems to prevent the comments from being sent to our server, so we can't tell what the users were trying to post that might have caused this error.

What could be causing this error to occur, and how can we prevent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one reason or another, [some of your users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382743/1114) are trying to submit comments containing what we might call "invalid characters". The Unicode code points from `\uD800` to `\uDFFF` are reserved so that the UCS-2 and UTF-16 text encodings can use pairs of them to identify other valid Unicode character code points that would otherwise be out-of-range for those encodings. For most modern encodings, including UTF-16, these code points are only allowed to occur in valid pairs that can be mapped to valid character code points when converting to another encoding; they can never exist as stand-alone "characters".

Unfortunately, JavaScript chose UCS-2 before UTF-16 was standardized, and UCS-2 *does* allow you to include surrogate characters on their own, without being paired to produce a valid code point. Because JavaScript allows it, browsers also accept it as input. This is a complication, but in most cases it doesn't actually get in users' way like you're experiencing. If your form didn't use JavaScript, your users would be able to submit a comment containing an unpaired surrogate without an error. How would that work?

The browser takes a common approach to encoding incompatibilities: any characters that can't be translated to the target encoding are replaced by `�` the Unicode replacement character `\uFFFD`. The browser automatically performs this replacement when encoding typical form data for submission. However, `jQuery.serialize()` doesn't have any such logic, and nor does the built-in `encodeURIComponent` function that it calls to encode form values. Instead, it just throws the `URIError` you're seeing. You can find this error specified in [Section 18.2.6.1.1: Runtime Semantics: `Encode`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-encode) of the ECMAScript 9 specification.

```javascript
encodeURIComponent('\uD83D') // URIError: malformed URI sequence
```

To reproduce browser-like form behaviour in JavaScript, you need to find and replace any instances where a "high surrogate" in the range `\uD800` to `\uDBFF` occurs without being followed by a "low surrogate" in the range `\uDC00` to `\uDFFF`, or vice-versa. That might look something like this:

```javascript
const replaceUnpairedSurrogates = s => s
  .replace(/[\uD800-\uDBFF]+([^\uDC00-\uDFFF]|$)/g, '�$1')
  .replace(/(^|[^\uD800-\uDBFF])[\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/g, '$1�');
```

(This function satisfies the "Constraints on Conversion Processes" required by the Unicode standard because it ensures that following valid characters are not mangled by the replacement. It does not conform to the optional "Substitution of Maximal Subparts" convention, because it may collapse consecutive unpaired surrogate characters down to a single replacement character.)

You're currently using `jQuery.serialize(this)` to encode the form data, which doesn't let us transform the form values before they're encoded. But `jQuery.serialize(this)` is just the same as `jQuery.param(jQuery.serializeArray(this))`, giving us a place to apply our replacement:

```javascript
jQuery(".post form.add-comment").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = jQuery.param(
    jQuery.serializeArray(this).map(
      ({name, value}) => {
        name: replaceUnpairedSurrogates(name),
        value: replaceUnpairedSurrogates(value),
      })
    )
  );
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/comment",
    data: data
  });
});
```

For the sake of testing, you can run the following to display one "invalid character" for copying:

```js
prompt('Copy this:', '\uD83D');
```